# Segmentation fault due to large 2D Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management

The below code is generated by parsed SIZE parameters which in this case anywhere you see '2512555' is a parsed SIZE parameter. The problem I have is the array is far too large and causes a Segmentation Fault.

Is there a way to overcome the Segmentation Fault without changing the SIZE parameter? This parameter can range from 0 - 400,000.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double templ25_mem1[2512555][2512555];

int main() 
{
  int templ25_mem1_index1=0;
  int templ25_mem1_index2=0;

    for(templ25_mem1_index1; templ25_mem1_index1 < 2512555; templ25_mem1_index1++)
    {
      for(templ25_mem1_index2; templ25_mem1_index2 < 2512555; templ25_mem1_index2++)
      {
            int rndRow = rand() % 2512555;
            int rndCol = rand() % 2512555;

            templ25_mem1[rndRow][rndCol] = 0x7FFFFFFF;
            templ25_mem1[rndRow][rndCol];    
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: My compiler doesn't even let this code compile.

Comment: The segmentation fault is probably the reason @ArthurDent

Comment: @Jason Segmentation faults are run-time errors. The fact you're getting one means your compiler allows this code to be compiled, which is strange.

Comment: @AlexQuilliam why is this not valid C? They are variables which have an initial value of 0.

Comment: Considering 8 bytes for double, you are allocating `8*2512555*2512555 = 50503 GB` does your machine support that

Comment: I think I have the distribution of the array completely wrong, I think my question should now be. How might I distribute 2512555 into the 2D array as opposed to the original which is 8*2512555*2512555 = 50503 GB

Comment: In extension to my previous comment, how might I distribute 2512555 as the number of elements in my 2D array?

Comment: @Jason is it 2512555 bytes or that many double variable (8*2512555) bytes

Comment: @VasanthAlagiriswamy I think that this number should be the number of indices in the given array

Comment: @Jason you can try `double temp[502511][5]`

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. You probably need to rethink your problem. Do you really need that many doubles (6*10^12)?

Comment: @VasanthAlagiriswamy but Vasanth, I need to have this array equally distribute upon each template generation. This SIZE parameter will change indefinitely

Comment: @Jason as far as I know this is not possible with 2512225, you need to have perfect square value, in your case 2512225 which is nearer to 2512555 and a perfect square where you can use `double temp[1585][1585]`

Comment: You could use mmap. This would allow you to allocate 1PB if you need it. This 1PB space is virtual, in the sense that it will only take 1PB if you actually write at the (1PB - 1) nth byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome the Segmentation Fault without changing the SIZE parameter, when size can be that large, you need to redesign your data structure(s).

For erxample, you can have this huge array in a temporary file where you swap parts into your main memory. You may also need two-level addressing because you must make sure you can address the array on disk (45TB is larger than the available address space and probably larger than the largest int).

Best could be to go over the requirements again and see if they really require such a large array, or if they allow for other approaches to achieve their goal(s).

Comment: Yeah, basically. My next question for you is, how may I distribute this array such that my 2D array will have 2512555 indices? Thanks

Comment: You take the largest amount of memory you want to/can use for the array. You divide SIZE by it and truncate to int. That is how many chunks in the file you need. The file may not be larger than the size of the `seek()` offset; if it is larger, you have to use multiple files. etcetera. For more questions: be creative & use your brains.